# Spring returning status 401 on all exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My SpringBoot app is returning 401 unauthorized on all failed requests.

SecurityConfig:

```
//JWT
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")   
                .antMatchers("/usr/adm/**").hasRole("ADMIN")   
                .antMatchers("/adminconfig").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/tech").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/refresh_token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER") 
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Anyone has any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal if authentication fails.

It comes 100% from

```
jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint
```

where some `AuthenticationException` is thrown during Authentication and inside this class is translated to 401 code.

Analyse `jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` or post more details to see why authentication fails