# 401 exception for every exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

When an application throws an error, it always returns 401.
I can't find what is the problem.

I am using Java(17) version, Spring boot 3.0.6

**Spring security config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
  private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
  private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/api/v1/docs/**").permitAll()
        // any request must be authenticated
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // session
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        // entry point
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        // provider
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        // filter
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // logout
        .logout().logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout").addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
        // clear context
        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

    return source;
  }

}
```

**Auth entry point class**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                       HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                       AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
    log.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
    httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
  }
}
```

**Auth filter**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final JwtService jwtService;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                  @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                  @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String username;

    // is token exist in header ?
    if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    // substr jwt
    jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
    // extract username from jwt
    username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);

    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

      var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
          .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
          .orElse(false);

      if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            null,
            userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
      }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

if the user calls a method that should throw an error, then the user will get 401 instead of 500

**Example**:

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muX6R.png)

**Stack trace**

```
2023-05-15T22:36:26.647+05:00 ERROR 10704 --- [nio-7000-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "core.clientss" does not exist
  Position: 43
2023-05-15T22:36:26.661+05:00 ERROR 10704 --- [nio-7000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select cast(c.id as varchar), c.name from core.clientss c where c.state_id = 0]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "core.clientss" does not exist
  Position: 43
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getMetaData(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getColumnCount(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy158.getClientsWithIdAndName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at uz.dafex.wsbpm.core.service.client.ClientService.getClientsWithIdAndName(ClientService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at uz.dafex.wsbpm.core.controller.client.ClientController.getClientsLight(ClientController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at uz.dafex.wsbpm.auth.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-15T22:36:26.670+05:00 ERROR 10704 --- [nio-7000-exec-2] u.d.w.a.s.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint    : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Comment: Is this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799277/spring-returning-status-401-on-all-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply added in `requestMatchers` '/error'.

```
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    // permit
    .requestMatchers(
        "/api/v1/auth/**",
        "/api/docs/**",
        "/error"
    ).permitAll()
    // any request must be authenticated
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: Worked for me too. I am wondering how did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace shows this is the issue of your database table relation

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "core.clientss" does not exist
```

Position: 43

**Please make necessary changes in your database table.**

Comment: His question is about 401 being thrown instead of 500. He has given the error as an example

Comment: I need this error to be returned to the client. And now it returns 401 instead of 500

Answer (score 0):

Your `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` is not checking for authorization while rethrowing any exception.

To check this hypothesis change `SC_UNAUTHORIZED` to `FORBIDDEN` and try again.

Comment: Now it returns 403 for every runtime exception.

Comment: This proves that your authentication entry point is not configured properly